# Meaning of "At Homes" in Ford Madox Ford's "Parade's End"

Tags: meaning, ford-madox-ford, parades-end

What does this paragraph mean in Ford Madox Ford's *Parade's End*?

> Nevertheless Macmaster **moved** in drawing-rooms that, with long curtains, blue china plates, large-patterned wallpapers and large, quiet mirrors, sheltered the long-haired of the Arts. And, as near as possible to the dear ladies who gave the **At Homes**, Macmaster could keep up the talk—a little magisterially. He liked to be listened to with respect when he spoke of Botticelli, Rossetti, and those early Italian artists whom he called "The Primitives." Tietjens had seen him there. And he didn't disapprove.

What is the meaning of the phrase "At homes"? Is this supposed to give an account of Macmaster in social gatherings? What does "moved" mean?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community The question is fine. Bad bot!

Answer (score 7):

An "At Home" is a social gathering, usually held in the afternoons by upper-class ladies. Wikipedia gives a more [detailed description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_Home_day) of this kind of event:

> The "At Home" day was a social custom in Victorian Britain, where
> women of gentle status would receive visitors on a specific day of the
> week.
>
> The woman would print calling cards indicating she would be "At Home"
> e.g. on "Fridays in April". Those of her acquaintances who had
> received the card could then call on her that day. It was considered
> impolite to visit unannounced on any other day, or to visit without
> having received a card. Guests should visit between three or four and
> six in the afternoon, and stay for a period from a quarter of an hour
> to an hour, depending on the level of intimacy with the hostess.

It is thus used as a way of labeling these "dear ladies" as rather refined and aristocratic (or certainly aspiring to that status). It was used in a similar way in Nesbit's *The Story of the Treasure Seekers* to mark a difference in social level:

> You know the people next door are very grand... they have an 'At
> Home' day, and people come in cabs.

"Moved" indeed signifies McMaster's social activities. In the same way that we may refer to someone "moving in high circles", he is moving from drawing-room to drawing-room, socialising with moneyed people with an interest in the arts.